# Get value of Json With Gson

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring-boot, gson

i don't arrive to get the name of the containerStatuses.
I tried this (regarding a precedent post), the error is reported on the get("name") with "The method get(String) is undefined for the type JsonElement".

Thanks for help

```
JsonObject data = new Gson().fromJson(myjsoncontent, JsonObject.class);
JsonArray items = data .get("items").getAsJsonArray();      
    for(JsonElement element : items){
         JsonObject object = element.getAsJsonObject();
         String containerstatusesname = object.get("status").getAsJsonObject().get("containerStatuses").getAsJsonArray().get(0).get("name").getAsString();
}
```

```
// My Json Content

{
    "kind": "Space",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {
        "selfLink": "something",
        "resourceVersion": "something"
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "status": {
                "containerStatuses": [
                 {
                   "name": "thisismyname"
                 }
                ]               
            }
        } 
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using gson emulating JSON.parse? Is using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

If you want to use gson it's better to create a class that matches your json data as:

```
public class ApiResponse {

    private String kind;
    private String apiVersion;
    private Metadata metadata;
    private List<Item> items;

    public List<String> getAllNames() {
        List<String> allNames = new ArrayList();
        for (Item item: items) {
            allNames.add(item.getStatus().get(0).getName());
        }
        return allNames;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        if (items.length == 0 || items.get(0).getStatus().length == 0) {
            return "";
        }
        return items.get(0).getStatus().get(0).getName();
    }

    class Metadata {
        private String selfLink;
        private String resourceVersion;
    }

    class Item {
        private List<StatusContainer> status;

        List<StatusContainer> getStatus() {
            return status;
        }
    }

    class StatusContainer {
        private String name;

        String getName() {
            return name;
        }
    }
}
```

And then execute:

```
ApiResponse response = gson.fromJson(myjsoncontent, ApiResponse.class);
String firstName = response.getFirstName();
```

And this way the response object will contain all the data of the parsed json. Notice you'll need to add the getters to access this properties if are kept private.

No need to emulate the result of JSON.parse and have JsonObject, JsonArray...

Comment: If i use your solution, (i'm new to java..) , how can i iterate over the list, and how can i get the value of the name researched ? thanks
In my first try, i was doing that, but another solution say me to do with JsonArray...

Comment: With getters. I add an example with getters for this specific case but you should have a look at how getters work. Notice in the example code the Metadata, Item and StatusContainer are package-private as well as their getters, it doesn't have to be this way but if they are package-private the public getter to access the data you want must be inside ApiResponse which is the public class.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, i understand much better, but ( there is 2 errors with getStatus.get(0) ) => `getStatus cannot be resolved or is not a field`

Comment: I'm trying your code now, but i get a `java.lang.NullPointerException: null` with this : 

`PodsApiResponse podscontent = new Gson().fromJson(response, PodsApiResponse.class);`
`System.out.println(podscontent.getFirstName());`
`String jsonofresult = podscontent.getFirstName();`
`return jsonofresult;`

Comment: Check the response you are getting now, it might not have a status with the name. In this case if you don't change the `getFirstName()` code and check that each item exists in the response before accessing to it it will throw a null pointer exception. Or you can rethrow the error in that method and catch that error outside, there are multiple ways of fixing this. The same would happen with the JsonObject, you would also have to check that each element exists there.

Comment: I use postman, and the element exists, i arrive to get "kind" which return "Space" but the `if(items.get(0).getStatuscontainer().get(0).getName() != null) {
         return items.get(0).getStatuscontainer().get(0).getName();
        }else {
         return "IlestNul";
        }`
returns nullpointer

Comment: I found the problem, the code that you give me has 2 errors , the "statuscontainer has a wrong name" and " the get status container is not a the good place, it has to be in Status class" :)

Comment: I see, well, but at least you'll get the idea of how gson works, now is just to check that the structure matches and the getters are ok. I still think it's way better to get it as a pojo object than to mimic JSON.parse behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change

```
.get(0).get("name")
```

to

```
.get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("name")
```

`JsonArray` returns `JsonElement`s when you iterate over it

Answer (score 0):

Get the Array Element as Object cause its structured as Object

```
.getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString();
```